# What is the best practice to return dynamic type from a REST API in SpringMVC

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I have implemented some REST API with springMVC+Jackson+hibernate.
All I needed to do is retrieve objects from database, return it as a list, the conversion to JSON is implicit.

But there is one problem. If I want to add some more information to those object before return/response. For example I am returning a list of "store" object, but I want to add a name of the person who is attending right now.
JAVA does not have dynamic type (how I solve this problem in C#). So, how do we solve this problem in JAVA?

I thought about this, and have come up with a few not so elegant solution.
1. use factory pattern, define another class which contain the name of that person.
2. covert store object to JSON objects (ObjectNode from jackson), put a new attribute into json objects, return json objects.
3. use reflection to inject a new property to store object, return objects, maybe SpringMVC conversion will generate JSON correctly?

option 1 looks bad, will end up with a lot of boiler plate class which doesn't really useful. option 2 looks ok, but is this the best we could do with springMVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**option 1**
Actually your JSON domain is different from your core domain. I would decouple them and create a seperate domain for your JSON objects, as this is a seperate concern and you don't want to mix it. This however might require a lot of 1-to-1 mapping. This is your option 1, with boilerplate. There are frameworks that help you with the boilerplate (such as dozer, MapStruct), but you will always have a performance penalty with frameworks that use generic reflection.

**option 2, 3**
If you really insist on hacking it in because it's only a few exceptions and not a common pattern, I would certainly not alter the JSON nodes or use reflection (your option 2 and 3). This is certainly not the way to do it in Java.

**option 4 [hack]**
What you could do is *extend* your core domain with new types that contain the extra information and in a post-processing step replace the old objects with the new domain objects:

```
 UnaryOperator<String> toJsonStores = domainStore -> toJsonStore(domainStore);
 list.replaceAll(toJsonStores);
```

where the `JSONStore` extends the domain `Store` and `toJsonStore` maps the domain `Store` to the `JSONStore` object by adding the person name.

That way you preserve type safety and keep the codebase comprehensive. But if you have to do it more then in a few exceptional cases, you should change strategy.

Comment: could you explain more on UnaryOperator? Is there a way to copy all attributes from domainStore to jsonStore if domainStore is the super class? does Lambda in JAVA 8 do that implicitly?

Comment: no you have to map it yourself, either by implementing the mapping logic or by using one of the frameworks I described in option 1

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a rest service that return list of objects that contain not just one type, but many type of objects? If so, Have you tried making the return type of that service method to `List<Object>`?
I recommend to create a abstract class `BaseRestResponse` that will be extended by all the items in the list which you want return by your rest service method. 
Then make return type as `List<BaseRestResponse>`.
BaseRestResponse should have all the common properties and the customized object can have the property **name** as you said

Comment: that's not what I meant. I need to add some extra properties to 1 type of object before returning/responding.